# How to rewriting a specific folder to root domain in iis

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

How to rewriting a specific folder to root domain, like **domain.org/folderxxxx** => **domain.org**. If i brows **domain.org** actually it brows **domain.org/folderxxxx**. I have tried below :

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="URL Alias" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.org/folderxxxx" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="domain.org{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

- If you will open in browser `domain.org` it will open content from this url `domain.org/folderxxxx`
- `domain.org/xyz` -> `domain.org/folderxxxx/xyz`
- But if you will open directly `domain.org/folderxxxx` It will disable rewriting will open content from the same `domain.org/folderxxxx`

Rule in your web.config:

```
<rule name="URL Alias" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/folderxxxx" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/folderxxxx/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```